# Помогите с регулярным выражением в PHP

Tags: php, html

- У меня есть **html** **файл**.
- Я хочу, чтобы всё, что **ссылалось неявно** **на файл**, *например*, **с изображением**,  **ссылалось** **на** **полный** **путь**.
- Я составил **регулярное выражение** `(src|href)="(.+)"`, но **понятия не имею**, как сделать, чтобы просто **добавлялось слово у первой кавычки** вместо замены всего выражения.
- Регулярное выражение выполняется **на языке PHP**.

Comment: Метки: `php`.. Тема: `У меня есть html файл`. Где связь? Раз так, то тут уже js нужен и на нём просто атрибут менять если есть совпадения

Comment: Исправил в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну как-то так

```
preg_replace('/(src|href)="(.+)"/', '$1="http://mysite.com/$2"', $data);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08ef65ae2ccd178b253272f0ab24d7586f105351

Comment: **Спасибо большое**

Comment: А как насчет `../images/`... ?